# Clean up unreachable generated files in Bazel

Tags: bazel

Suppose I have a very minimal project with an empty `WORKSPACE` and a single package defined at the project root that simply uses `touch` to create a file called `a`, as follows:

```
genrule(
  name = "target",
  cmd = "touch $@",
  outs = ["a"],
)
```

If I now run

```
bazel build //:target
```

the package will be "built" and the `a` file will be available under `bazel-genfiles`.

Suppose I now change the `BUILD` to write the output to a different file, as follows:

```
genrule(
  name = "target",
  cmd = "touch $@",
  outs = ["b"],
)
```

Building the same target will result in the file `b` being available under `bazel-genfiles`. `a` will still be there though, even though at this point it's "unreachable" from within the context of the build definition.

Is there a way to ask Bazel to perform some sort of "garbage collection" and remove files (and possibly other content) generated by previous builds that are no longer reachable as-per the current build definition, without getting rid of the entire directory? The `bazel clean` command seems to adopt the latter behavior.

[There seems to be a feature in the works](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5139), but apparently it cannot be performed on demand, but rather it executes automatically as soon as a certain threshold has been reached.

Comment: this is a spot on question, the next level for bazel to have cache intelligence relative to the state of the repository. This sentence pretty much clarifies the current state of affairs:  *Since Bazel does not garbage-collect the directory, you might want to automate a periodic cleanup of this directory.* 
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/remote-caching.html#disk-cache

Cleanup is effectively left as an exercise for the user. Could run a chron job that polls the disk space and run a clean if above some threshold, etc. Otherwise it's a manual step.

Answer (score 2):

Note that running `bazel clean` will not actually delete the external directory. To remove all external artifacts, use `bazel clean --expunge`

Comment: I don't want to remove all external artifacts but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`bazel clean` is the way to remove these.

The stale outputs aren't visible to actions, provided you build with sandboxing. (Not yet available on Windows, only on Linux and macOS.)

What trouble do these files make?

Comment: I just wanted to free up some space from previous runs. I tried `bazel clean` but it removes all the files, also those that are reachable in the current build definition and that I'd like to keep cached.

Comment: @stefanobaghino did you find a solution to that problem in the end?

Comment: Nothing that deletes unreachable files, unfortunately.

Comment: "What trouble do these files make?" They are visible on Windows and can interfere with builds.

Comment: the trouble these files make is that bazel can rapidly consume a lot of disk space for very large and complex repositories. Bazel cache management has tradeoffs for keeping one around on like a build agent running multiple jobs where you can potentially leverage cache hits but run the risk of eating up too much disk space. If you clean each the cache each run you preclude using the cache that would afford avoiding running tests etc from what I understand.